# BizTalk or SSIS

Tags: biztalk

Had a requirement to export the daily snapshot from a table, transform some values then save to a positioned file sent via ftp. The table itself estimating around 2-3m rows, each row has around 20 columns. Given the volume, a little hesitate to use the biztalk sql adapter, thinking to use another ETL tool (e.g. SSIS) to perform the select/transform/export to a flat file then use BizTalk to simplely dump the file to the ftp. The alternative is of course has BizTalk do all the job, poll the table, transform in the map etc.

What's the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `BizTalk` for this requirement, file with 2-3 M of rows, when get suspended in BizTalk it will hold this huge message on to the `BizTalk` DB.

Just use `SSIS` FTP Task to transfer your converted file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is much better at large batches than BizTalk.

BizTalk's strength is in lots of small messages being processed in parallel.

So SSIS for this scenario to create the file and BizTalk to move it sounds best.